# SQL EXP raising Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql, sql-server

For whatever reason, the below is failing as a result of an Arithmetic overflow error. I've tried casting and converting with no success. Any ideas?

```
DECLARE 
    @s INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', @EndDate),
    @e INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', @StartDate)

DECLARE @X FLOAT = @s-@e

SELECT EXP(@X)
```

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type float.

Comment: @Diado @X is an acceptable value within that range. @X = 1728000

Comment: Scrap my previous comment - didn't read the error message properly. Been a long day, sorry

Comment: What are you trying to do? Float has limits too, Like 1.79E+308. Max number that can be calculated by `exp` ~700. Your `@X` can be much bigger

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overflowing the variable, you will need more bits. You can use float(n) to increase the number of bits, or just use decimal which uses 17 bytes.

```
DECLARE @X decimal = @s-@e
```